# SQL SELECT command slow down when used in C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server

I execute a SQL statement directly in SQL Server Management Studio, and it is very fast, but when I try to do the same in a C# program, it is very slow! I use exactly the same parameters for the query, but it seems to react differently...

Here is the code :

```
public static DataTable GetInfosPrepa(String activite, String depot, String cle_prepa, int sortie, int waiting)
{
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLProd"].ToString(); //Récupération de la chaîne de connexion
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); //Nouvelle connexion à la base de donnée
        myConnection.Open(); //On ouvre la connexion

        String query = "";

        if (waiting == 0)
        {
            query = @"Select * from reflex.hlprenp 
                      where pecact = @activite 
                        and pecdpo = @depot 
                        and cast(penann as varchar) + cast(penpre as varchar) = @numero ";
        }
        else
        {
            query = @"Select * 
                      from reflex.hlprenp, reflex.hlprplp, reflex.hlodpep 
                      left join reflex.hlvaicp on oenobj = vcnobj 
                      where pecact = p1cact 
                        and pecdpo = p1cdpo 
                        and penpre = p1npre 
                        and penann = p1nann 
                        and p1cact = oecact 
                        and p1cdpo = oecdpo 
                        and p1nano = oenann 
                        and p1nodp = oenodp 
                        and vccicm = 'STATUT' 
                        and vcvaic = 'WAITING' 
                        and pecact = @activite 
                        and pecdpo = @depot 
                        and cast(penann as varchar) + cast(penpre as varchar) = @numero ";
        }

        if (sortie < 2)
        {
            query += "and petsop=@sortie";
        }

        SqlDataAdapter source = new SqlDataAdapter(query, myConnection);
        source.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activite", activite);
        source.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depot", depot);
        source.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", cle_prepa);
        source.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortie", sortie);

        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        source.Fill(data);
        myConnection.Close();

        return data;
    }
```

(the request slow down when waiting != 0)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: *"it seems to react differently"* Do you have actual performance data or do you just *feel* it's slower? You have to measure performance, not guess it.

Comment: Is it still slow if you run without the debugger attached?

Comment: In sqlserver managment studio : less than 1 seconds, in C# : more than 10 seconds...

Comment: It seems to cause network bandwith between your application server and dbserver. I am assuming that your management studio is running in same machine with dbserver.

Comment: It's not a connection time problem, the problem is in the line "source.Fill(data)", it's very long  for some reason

Comment: @Rainman yes, it runs in the same machine, and usually it doesn't change execution time ^^

Comment: Start removing the AddWithValue and use a proper Add specifying the size of the parameter. This will allow the Query optimizer to reuse the same query without recompiling it.

Comment: This problem is called _parameter sniffing_. You could read about it here https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ and check there the solutions provided there.

Comment: So, I think, it is not relevant with query optimization. SQL Server streams data results from a specific port(mostly 443 by default) and if remote machine network bandwith is low, data result will be delay to complete. I suggest you that retrieve specific columns instead of "Select * from". Reduce retrieving data size.

Comment: Changing the AddWithValue to Add fixed the issue... waw... I never heard about this problem, I've been on this project for almost 2 years and that didn't happened... Great job ! Someone can post it as the solution so I can set the topic as "solved" please ?

Comment: Consider executing `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` before testing actual query performance and execution plan. Thus you can ensure that the query performs well on "cold" buffers, when nothing is cached. In my case, that was the reason of different behavior between SQL Management Studio and .Net application.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Are any of the columns in your table `varchar` rather than `nvarchar`?

Comment: @marc_s I have to use old-style JOINS because new one are not supported by our database

Comment: @alexay68: but in the "else" case - you **ARE** using a `left join` - that's a proper ANSI/SQL JOIN......

Comment: @marc_s Oh I see, you mean using the  key word "JOIN" even if I don't need a left or a right join ? I simply never learned to do it that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I try to do the same in a C# program, it is very slow !  I
>   use exactly the same parameters for the query...

To use "exactly the same parameters" you should use `sp_executesql` from SSMS,
 but I guess you used `variables` in SSMS.

Your problem is called **parameter sniffing**, this means that when you really use parameters they are "sniffed" at the first execution and the plan is built for these "sniffed" values.

When you use `variables` in SSMS they are NOT sniffed (unless `recompile` option is specified), distribution statistics cannot be used in this case and you get  different execution plan.

Comment: Just missing what he should do to prevent parameter sniffing (`Add` instead of `AddWithValue`).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter In SQL code optimize for unknown will prevent parameter sniffing; I just have no idea about C# and  AddWithValue / Add, please feel free to adit the answer, I wrote it prior to see the comment about AddWithValue / Add, I imagine the first just put the constants instead of using parameters as parameters